# C++: Make class and some of its data members only available in namespace

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces, member

Is it possible to make a class only available inside the namespace? Or is there maybe another way, without using a namespace?
I'm working on creating a framework and don't want the user of this framework to have access to all classes, only to specific ones.

BUT: The user should be able to reach all definitions anyway for creating pointer vars to these classes. Additionally he should not be able to access all data members of these classes, but I want my framework to have access to all data members.

Is that even possible?

**Example(just as an explanation for my request):**

```
/* T2DApp.h */
namespace T2D {
    // I don't want the user to be able to create an instance of this class (only pointer vars), but the framework should be able to.
    class T2DApp {
    public:
        // constructor, destructor... //

        SDL_Window*  Window;
        SDL_Surface* Surface;

        bool Running = false;
    }
}

/* T2D.h */
#include "T2DApp.h"

void init();

/* T2D.cpp */
#include "T2D.h"

void init() {
    T2D::T2DApp app;       // function in framework is able to create new instance of T2DApp.
    app.Window.Whatever(); // every data member should be available to framework directly without getter methods.
    app.Window.Whatever(); // dito
    app.Running = true;    // dito
}

/* [cpp of user] */
#include "T2D.h"

void main(etc.) {
    ...
    T2D::T2DApp app;    // User shouldn't be able to create an instance of T2DApp
    T2D::T2DApp* p_app; // but he should still be able to "see" the class definition for creating pointers
    ...
    p_app.Running = true;     // User shouldn't be able to access this data member
    p_app.Window.Whatever();  // But he should be able to access the other data members
    p_app.Surface.Whatever(); // dito
    ...
}
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: It's common to have a `namespace detail` or `namespace internal` around the `T2DApp`, and documentation to say "anything inside the namespace `detail` / `internal` are not to be manually touched by the user"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with [`Pimpl` idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl):

> "Pointer to implementation" or "pImpl" is a C++ programming technique that removes implementation details of a class from its object representation by placing them in a separate class, accessed through an opaque pointer.

Comment: Ah, I remember I have read about this technique once; but is it true, that it isn't recommended to use this idiom?

Comment: @TobbeWidner This technique has a cost of an extra memory allocation during costruction and indirection through a pointer. Both of these issues can be eliminated by using `std::aligned_storage` instead of the pointer, however, the size of the implementation class must be exposed in the header in this case. E.g. https://github.com/sqjk/pimpl_ptr

Comment: Is it maybe cleaner to just write a wrapper class, in which I define additional methods and data members, which just reference to those members of the class `T2DApp`, that the user needs to have access to? Or is that a relatively big resource killer?

Comment: @TobbeWidner Each reference in the wrapper class is going to take the size of a pointer, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: That's correct. I know it's not very "clean" either. I guess I will have to try with pimpl anyway xD